# How to shut down computer immediately in Win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

Back in (Windows XP?) times i had written .bat file which when clicked like normal icon would shut down my PC immediately, no questions no update instalations.

I copied it from somewhere , so I can not remember how to do it..
Also Win 10 might be different.

How to achieve that? (Or something very similar if that .bat trick doesnt work on win 10) ?

Cheers!  ♥  ♥

(P.S. Somebody in comments said it is better to wait , etc. I want to mess with MY COMPUTER WHICH I BOUGHT, if it burns it burns! )

Comment: Windows 10 is different and sometimes it really has to install updates. So no, just don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to mess with your computer and I do not take any responsibility for any damage you might do.

Open an Admin Command Prompt. A regular prompt for an Admin User should work as well.

Type the following command then press enter: shutdown /p and then press Enter.

Your computer should now shut down immediately without installing or processing any updates.

Type Shutdown /?  for all the parameters that the Shutdown command can process.

Good luck and remember that if you are successful in not doing updates on shutdown, they will happen on startup (probably 2 cycles with attendant restarts along the way).

Comment: Yeaaa! thanks! Can I put it somehow in .bat file?? make like shortcut?

Comment: You should be able to put shutdown /p in a batch file and put the batch file on the desktop. It works in a regular command prompt as well.